# Tensor object has no attribute ndim

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I am trying to get a trained model to output it's predictions for segmentation task using the following code.

```
import h5py
import tifffile as tiff

from cnn_functions import nikon_getfiles, get_image, run_models_on_directory, get_image_sizes, segment_nuclei, segment_cytoplasm, dice_jaccard_indices
from model_zoo import sparse_bn_feature_net_31x31 as cyto_fn

import os
import numpy as np

direc_name = "C:/Users/Zein/Documents/Neural_Networks/CNN/"
data_location = os.path.join(direc_name, 'RawImages')

cyto_location = os.path.join(direc_name, 'Cytoplasm')
mask_location = os.path.join(direc_name, 'Masks')

cyto_channel_names = ['phase']

trained_network_cyto_directory = "C:/Users/Zein/Documents/Neural_Networks/CNN/trained_networks/"

cyto_prefix = "2017-03-06_Kcells_all_31x31_bn_feature_net_31x31_

win_cyto = 15
image_size_x, image_size_y = get_image_sizes(data_location, cyto_channel_names)[0:2]

list_of_cyto_weights = []
for j in range(2):
    cyto_weights = os.path.join(trained_network_cyto_directory,  cyto_prefix + str(j) + ".h5")
    list_of_cyto_weights += [cyto_weights]

cytoplasm_predictions = run_models_on_directory(data_location, cyto_channel_names, cyto_location, model_fn = cyto_fn, 
    list_of_weights = list_of_cyto_weights, image_size_x = image_size_x, image_size_y = image_size_y, 
    win_x = win_cyto, win_y = win_cyto, split = False)

cytoplasm_masks = segment_cytoplasm(cytoplasm_predictions, nuclear_masks = nuclear_masks, mask_location = mask_location, smoothing = 1, num_iters = 120)
```

However I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3ce4003728e5> in <module>()
      1 cytoplasm_predictions = run_models_on_directory(data_location, cyto_channel_names, cyto_location, model_fn = cyto_fn, 
      2         list_of_weights = list_of_cyto_weights, image_size_x = image_size_x, image_size_y = image_size_y,
----> 3     win_x = win_cyto, win_y = win_cyto, split = False)

C:\Users\Zein\Documents\Neural_Networks\CNN\cnn_functions.py in run_models_on_directory(data_location, channel_names, output_location, model_fn, list_of_weights, n_features, image_size_x, image_size_y, win_x, win_y, std, split, process, save)
   1480 
   1481         batch_input_shape = (1,len(channel_names),image_size_x+win_x, image_size_y+win_y)
-> 1482         model = model_fn(batch_input_shape = batch_input_shape, n_features = n_features, weights_path = list_of_weights[0])
   1483         n_features = model.layers[-1].output_shape[1]
   1484 

C:\Users\Zein\Documents\Neural_Networks\CNN\model_zoo.py in sparse_bn_feature_net_31x31(batch_input_shape, n_features, reg, init, weights_path)
    353         model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    354         model.add(Activation('relu'))
--> 355         model.add(sparse_MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(d, d)))
    356         d *= 2
    357         model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64,3, strides=d, kernel_initializer=init, padding='valid', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg)))

C:\Users\Zein\Anaconda3\envs\TF352\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in add(self, layer)
    464                           output_shapes=[self.outputs[0]._keras_shape])
    465         else:
--> 466             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    467             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    468                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

C:\Users\Zein\Anaconda3\envs\TF352\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    583 
    584             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 585             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    586             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    587 

C:\Users\Zein\Documents\Neural_Networks\CNN\cnn_functions.py in call(self, x, mask)
   1128                                                                                 strides=self.strides,
   1129                                                                                 border_mode=self.border_mode,
-> 1130                                         dim_ordering=self.dim_ordering)
   1131                 return output
   1132 

C:\Users\Zein\Documents\Neural_Networks\CNN\cnn_functions.py in _pooling_function(self, inputs, pool_size, strides, border_mode, dim_ordering)
   1121     def _pooling_function(self, inputs, pool_size, strides,
   1122                           border_mode, dim_ordering):
-> 1123                 output = sparse_pool(inputs, pool_size = pool_size, stride = strides[0])
   1124                 return output
   1125 

C:\Users\Zein\Documents\Neural_Networks\CNN\cnn_functions.py in sparse_pool(input_image, stride, pool_size, mode)
    252         for offset_x in range(stride):
    253                 for offset_y in range(stride):
--> 254                         pooled_array +=[pool_2d(input_image[:, :, offset_x::stride, offset_y::stride], pool_size, stride = (1,1), mode = mode, pad = (0,0), ignore_border = True)]
    255                         counter += 1
    256 

C:\Users\Zein\Anaconda3\envs\TF352\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\signal\pool.py in pool_2d(input, ws, ignore_border, stride, pad, mode, ds, st, padding)
    127             pad = padding
    128 
--> 129     if input.ndim < 2:
    130         raise NotImplementedError('pool_2d requires a dimension >= 2')
    131     if ignore_border is None:

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I'm using Keras with a Tensorflow backend, however the pool2_d function is from Theano. Is that the issue or can Keras use functions from both TF and Theano in the same script? Or perhaps the call is simply depreciated?

Comment: It looks like your keras installation is broken and trying to use tensorflow and theano at the same time.